# Canvas Drawing in QML - Qt

Tags: qt, html5-canvas, qml

I have a written a simple program. I am able to see two minor spokes between the angles I am drawing, and I am not sure why.

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    Canvas
    {
        width: 360
        height: 360
        onPaint:
        {
            var x = 140
            var y = 140
            var radius = 140;
            var startangle = -90
            var endangle = 30
            var context = getContext("2d");
            for(var j=0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(x, y);
                context.arc(x, y, radius, (startangle)*(Math.PI/180), (endangle)*(Math.PI/180), false) //x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, anticlockwise
                context.fillStyle = "blue"
                context.fill();
                startangle += 120
                endangle += 120
                context.closePath();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output:

[image: My output]

The expected drawing should not have spokes (stroke lines).

Comment: It is a side effect of anti-aliasing. There’s nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Is it possible to remove the anti-aliasing effect?

Comment: Set [antialiasing property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#antialiasing-prop) to false.

Comment: Done. Now the spoke got removed. Thanks a tonne

Comment: @Meefte thanks for your response. I think that can be proposed as the best answer.